# Separate 4 border (border bottom) and make space between columns (th) using padding css

Tags: css, wordpress

I used padding and border spacing and other codes but it's not applying, even margin is not applying, how to fix?

**Image of the table margin:**

[image: image of the table margin]

I want my output to be like this:

[image]

> here is my css codes please check if I enter some wrong css codes, so
>   I can check my mistakes.

```
.dialog-ovelay .dialog table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

.dialog-ovelay .dialog th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 70px 15px 0px 15px;
    width: 25%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #1E1C1C;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.dialog-ovelay .dialog td.tdtitle {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    padding-top: 15px;

}

.dialog-ovelay .dialog th.tdtitle {
    padding-top: 15px;

}

.dialog-ovelay .dialog th.tdtitlefing {
    padding-top: 20px;

}


.dialog-ovelay .dialog td {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #1E1C1C;

}

td.imgprev-front, td.imgprev-back {
    padding-bottom: 160px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `padding-bottom`?

Comment: no I want to padding the right and left so the border will seperate (have spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `border-collapse` attribute. It's default to `separate`, so your CSS might changed this value to `border-collapse: collapse;`

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Home</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Space</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">StackOverFlow</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Kepler</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Saturn</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: its not applying sir, and I want to make space like 10px, just make sure that the columns are part aways (see the output I want to be)

Comment: I think it's better if you show us all of your CSS & HTML here. It's better & easier to help

Comment: @JTDD I adjust the code to increase spacing. You can check again